# How to Make a div not affected by the style of its parent div placed in external css file

Tags: html, styles, parent

In design mode i want to place some text in a div but this div is affected by its parent div when shown in browser its style is changed...So can someone tell me how to make this not effected by its parent div or or style of parent div of that external css file.